# Find the half range cosine fourier series expansion for $f(x)=(x-1)^2,\quad 0<x<1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Find the half range cosine fourier series expansion for
$$f(x)=(x-1)^2,\quad 0<x<1$$

and hence deduce that
$$\pi^2=8\left(\frac 1 {1^2}+\frac 1 {3^2}+\frac 1 {5^2}+\ldots\right)\tag{1}$$

**My work**

I have derived that the expansion is
$$f(x)=\frac 1 3+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 4 {n^2\pi^2} \cos n\pi x$$
But I could not deduce that $(1)$.

Comment: Set $x=0$ then $x=1$ then subtract.

Comment: but in x=0 and 1 the function is not defined know...then how can i do this??@AlexeyBurdin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f$ as a periodic function of $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ as
$$
f(x)=(x−1)^2, \hspace{5 mm} 0\le x<1
$$
Set $x=0$, then
$$
f(0)=1=\frac 1 3+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 4 {n^2\pi^2}
$$

So we have
$$
\dfrac{2}{3}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 4 {n^2\pi^2} \hspace{4 mm} \text{and} \hspace{4 mm} \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2}
$$

And set $x\to1^{-}$, then
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to1^{-}}f(x)=0=\frac 1 3+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 4 {n^2\pi^2} \cos n\pi
$$

Thus
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1 {(2n-1)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1 {(2n)^2}
\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1 {(2n-1)^2}-\frac1{4}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1 {n^2}
\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1 {(2n-1)^2}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{24}
\end{align}

So
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1 {(2n-1)^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}
$$

Comment: how it hold even the fuction is not defined on 1 and 2.

Comment: $f$ becomes a periodic function of $1$ so it repeats on $[1,2]$ from $[0,1]$, and that is why you get $f(x)=\frac 1 3+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 4 {n^2\pi^2} \cos n\pi x$.

Comment: ya,,, thanks for the comment